# How do I get the resources of a working set?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I know that Eclipse working sets are very flexible and customizable. They are made of elements which implement `IAdaptable` Which can be anything. However, in many (most) cases, working sets are used to define a set of resources.

In case these elements can be seen as resources (e.g. `IJavaProject`), is there a universal (or formal) way to programatically translate these elements to resources?

Eventually, I need to determine whether a given resource is in a working set, so an answer in that direction is acceptable as well.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think there's any way around the `IAdaptable` route.  You can do something like this, given an `IWorkingSet ws`:

```
List<IResource> resources = new ArrayList(); // or LinkedList
for (IAdaptable adaptable: ws.getElements()) {
  IResource r = (IResource) adaptable.getAdapter(IResource.class);
  if (r != null) resources.add(r);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, but I wanted to be sure I didn't miss anything. I'll keep this open for a while longer to see if there are any other options.